# MongoDB writeback exception

Tags: mongodb

Our mongodb cluster in production, is a sharded cluster with 3 replica sets with 3 server each one and, of course, another 3 config servers.

We also have 14 webservers that connect directly to mongoDb throw the mongos process that are running in each of this webservers (clients).

The entire cluster receive 5000 inserts per minute.

Sometimes, we start getting exceptions from our java applications when it wants to perform operations to the mongoDb.

This is the stackTrace:

```
caused by com.mongodb.MongoException: writeback
com.mongodb.CommandResult.getException(CommandResult.java:100)
com.mongodb.CommandResult.throwOnError(CommandResult.java:134)
com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector._checkWriteError(DBTCPConnector.java:142)
com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.say(DBTCPConnector.java:183)
com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.say(DBTCPConnector.java:155)
com.mongodb.DBApiLayer$MyCollection.insert(DBApiLayer.java:270)
com.mongodb.DBApiLayer$MyCollection.insert(DBApiLayer.java:226)
com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(DBCollection.java:147)
com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(DBCollection.java:90)
com.mongodb.DBCollection$insert$0.call(Unknown Source)
```

If I check the mongos process throw the rest _status command that it provides, it returns a 200OK. We could fix the problem restarting the tomcat that we are using and restarting the mongos process but I would like to find a final solution to this problem. It's not a happy solution to have to restart everything in the middle of the night.

When this error happens, maybe 2 or 3 another webservers got the same error at the same time, so I imagine that there is a problem in the entire mongoDb cluster, no a problem in a single isolated webserver.

Does anyone know why mongo returns a writeback error? and how to fix it?

I'm using mongoDb 2.2.0.

Thanks in advance.

Fer

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are seeing the Writeback error "leak" into the getLastError output and then continue to be reported even when the operation in question had not errored.  This was an issue in the earlier versions of MongoDB 2.2, and has since been fixed, see:

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-7958
https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-7369
https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-4532

As of writing this answer, I would recommend 2.2.4, but basically whatever the latest 2.2 branch is, to resolve your problem.